# writing file on sdcard privately for application android

Tags: android

I am writing audio data as in amr file format in sdcard.

```
    File file = new File(dir, "test.amr");
    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        f.write(audioData);
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Its working properly but my problem is it shows in other applications as well like in default media player of android OS.

My question is how can write a file on sdcard which is only accessible to my application.Not to other applications on device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, all files on SD card are accessible to all apps.

To keep files private, create them in application's local directory.
Location of app's private folder is determined by:

```
String dir = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.app", 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
```

Other option: make empty ".nomedia" file in your folder on SD card, then files inside won't (should not) show in media players.

Comment: Thanks , that is a good solution but i can give any extension or `.nomedia` is the only option.

Answer (score 2):

Files on SD Card, some way or another, will be accessible by all, you cannot change that. You should use the [***internal storage***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By
>   default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible on API 9(android 2.3) or higher. From 2.3, there comes a new Class called `StorageManager`. The OBB filesystem may meet your demand.
Sorry, I am a greenhand on Android and I can not give you a good example, however, you can [See the official document here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html)

Comment: thanks...  any idea about how to save all data files from OBB unpacked data in the directory specified by getExternalFilesDir()

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder on SD card, store your files there.

And create a file named `.nomedia` in that folder to hide the files in that folder from being listed in other apps.

Any folder containing a file named `.nomedia` won't be scanned by MediaServer and thus won't be listed in Music player etc.