# How can I hide a folder on an SD card?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application, I save more than 500 images on an SD card.

Normally, anyone can access that folder and may be modify that folder. I want to hide that folder. I create that folder from my activity and download all images from server.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277254/how-can-i-hide-my-data-folder-in-android

Comment: https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl/archives/master

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any folder in Linux and Android by prefixing `"."` to it name say I wanna hide folder `Android` then I would name that as `.Android`.

But that will hide it from ordinary File browsers if the user mount the SD-Card on `Windows` machine or use ['Astro'](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro) from market he can see and thus modify it.

So the bottom-line is this is the only measure you can take or there is no option another option is to encrypt file but then also user is able to delete the file.

Comment: Thxs for your comment ... i agree with u....
but can u tell me other option to use images in my application..
because android support only 25 MB size of APK..
and my application is already 20 MB now...

Comment: i have also same problem. so i just get data from server temporary and  destroy it. but question raise in your mind is that "what about connectivity and loading and performance?" then i said use asynTask

Comment: I faced similar problem so I used a trick what I did when files are downloaded I cut starting 32 bytes from them and store them in sqlite this way the file is corrupt and when I want to show the file I add that 32 bytes gain to file to display it so no matter where user mount SD card it will not be displayed but if the user had rooted the device the he has access to db so he can by manually adding the bytes to respective files but I dont think any would take such pain :P

Answer (score 0):

One partial solution is to make empty ".nomedia" file in your folder on SD card, then files inside won't (should not) show in media players.

Otherwise, regarding permissions on SD card, see this: [writing file on sdcard privately for application android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442895/writing-file-on-sdcard-privately-for-application-anddroid)